# How can be created an action on Menu Bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add an icon to a Menu Bar in an Android application; once pressed, the activity will change. How Can I do this ?

[image]

Something like the (2) icon I want, not the (3).

Comment: There are many tutorials to do this. Please read: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html - Edit: I notice you have taken that image directly from this page. Why not try it out and then post your code if you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/) for ActionBar with menu items ?

Please check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) for further details of **ActionBar**.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already grasp the concept of action menus and inflating it from an XML, this is all you'd need to do:

In your menu_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:orderInCategory="99"
        android:title="@string/label_logout"
        app:showAsAction="always" <!-- THIS LINE will make your menu ALWAYS appear as an icon. --> />
</menu>
```

All you need to take notice is `app:showAsAction="always"` as it will make your menu always appear as an icon rather than in an overflow menu (that three dotted icon on the right-most).

If you're not familiar with action menus then this is the best time to learn. [Head here to start](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Ftraining%2Fbasics%2Factionbar%2Fadding-buttons.html&ei=6w2VVfeWGIOB8QWZ9LmwDw&usg=AFQjCNHEh5ZIXEMGc14Nw-pC8cq1N_jZcQ&sig2=mRx2htdtDRKvR6CK-r3qhg&bvm=bv.96952980,d.dGc).